# unwanted breakline in .csv file after merging file

Tags: bash

I have a list of file:

```
youyou.log
youyou.log.1.gz
youyou.log.2.gz
```

First, there are merged :

```
find . -name "youyou.log.*.gz" -print0 | sort -z -rn -t. -k4 | xargs -0 zcat | cat - youyou.log > youyou_complete.log
```

then I select what I need:

```
 awk '{OFS=","}{print $1, $2, $14, $15, $16 }' youyou_complete.csv > youyou_processed.csv
```

the `youyou_processed.csv` is clean but I scroll and arrive at `youyou.log` section, there are breakline everywhere.

Any reason why it's happening?

**** Update

I have noticed all the chaos starts after `awk` command, is there anything wrong there ?

Comment: Does your `find` command do really find your _youyou.log_?

Comment: @JohnGoofy it does, I changed to` find -name "youyou.lo*" | sort -rn | xargs cat > youyou_complete.log` but the issue remain the same right after `awk`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge *all* files, you need to use

```
find . -name "youyou.lo*"
```

Otherwise you will skip the first `youyou.log`, that's why you got scrumbled eggs.

Comment: I tried this `find  -name "youyou.lo*" | sort -rn | xargs cat > youyou_complete.log` the scramble is still there... Is there anything wrong with `awk` command ?

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to the data, but we can't see your input, nor your desired output.

Comment: that's right, I have an extra $value that doesn't exist affecting my .csv file :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first command, your output goes to youyou_complete.**log**.
But in the second command, your input is taken from youyou_complete.**csv**.

Change one of these to make them identical, and you're good to go.

Comment: I forgot to mention something that affect what I wrote at the beginning, in between I am doing :`grep -w BLABLA youyou_complete.log > youyou_complete0.csv`    then this will be used at the  AWK command